# Unsorted list into nested json with children

Tags: java, json, ldap

I have an unsorted list (more precisley a list of LDAP DNs) like so:

```
ou=org02,ou=org,dc=example,dc=com
ou=org,dc=example,dc=com
ou=org01,ou=org,dc=example,dc=com
ou=suborg01,ou=org01,ou=org,dc=example,dc=com
ou=suborg02,ou=org01,ou=org,dc=example,dc=com
ou=org03,ou=org,dc=example,dc=com
ou=subsuborg01,ou=suborg01,ou=org01,ou=org,dc=example,dc=com
ou=suborg03,ou=org01,ou=org,dc=example,dc=com
```

And i would like to transform this list into a nested json structure like so:

```
{
  "key": "ou=org,dc=example,dc=com",
  "children": [
    {
      "key": "ou=org01,ou=org,dc=example,dc=com"
      "children": [
        {
          "key": "ou=suborg01,ou=org01,ou=org,dc=example,dc=com"
          "children": [
            {
              "key": "ou=subsuborg01,ou=suborg01,ou=org01,ou=org,dc=example,dc=com"
            }
          ]
        },
        {
          "key": "ou=suborg02,ou=org01,ou=org,dc=example,dc=com"
        },
        {
          "key": "ou=suborg03,ou=org01,ou=org,dc=example,dc=com"
        }
      ]
    },
    {
      "key": "ou=org02,ou=org,dc=example,dc=com"
    }
  ]
}
```

What is the most efficient way to do so? Preferable in Java.

Comment: Split them on `,` comma, build a `Map<String, Map>` starting with last element from split. Upon printing result, merge "node" will exactly one child.

Comment: What have you tried? Where are you stuck and/or where is it failing?

Comment: @Andreas I see, you are building the whole tree, which will be a complexity of O(n*2). I can even ignore the first 3 parts (ou=org,dc=example,dc=com), since this is a fixed value i know about.

Comment: @ErwinBolwidt I had a similar idea like Andreas's answer. Just trying to figure out, what is the most efficient way to do so.

Comment: @Sylnois Why would building the whole tree be _O(n*2)_, given that there is no such thing? It is _O(n)_. And how did you expect to do this without building the tree, given that inputs are not in order? The first leaf node of the result is the second-last input!!!

Answer (score 0):

//import java.util.ArrayList;
//import org.bson.Document;

```
    Document root = new Document();
    ArrayList rootChildren = new ArrayList();
    Document rootChildren0 = new Document();
    ArrayList rootChildren0Children = new ArrayList();
    Document rootChildren0Children0 = new Document();
    ArrayList rootChildren0Children0Children = new ArrayList();
    Document rootChildren0Children0Children0 = new Document();
    Document rootChildren0Children1 = new Document();
    Document rootChildren0Children2 = new Document();
    Document rootChildren1 = new Document();

    root.append("key", "ou=org,dc=example,dc=com");

    rootChildren0.append("key", "ou=org01,ou=org,dc=example,dc=com");

    rootChildren0Children0.append("key", "ou=suborg01,ou=org01,ou=org,dc=example,dc=com");

    rootChildren0Children0Children0.append("key", "ou=subsuborg01,ou=suborg01,ou=org01,ou=org,dc=example,dc=com");

    rootChildren0Children1.append("key", "ou=suborg02,ou=org01,ou=org,dc=example,dc=com");

    rootChildren0Children2.append("key", "ou=suborg03,ou=org01,ou=org,dc=example,dc=com");

    rootChildren1.append("key", "ou=org02,ou=org,dc=example,dc=com");

    if (!rootChildren.isEmpty()) {
        root.append("children", rootChildren);
    }
    if (!rootChildren0Children.isEmpty()) {
        rootChildren0.append("children", rootChildren0Children);
    }
    if (!rootChildren0Children0Children.isEmpty()) {
        rootChildren0Children0.append("children", rootChildren0Children0Children);
    }
    if (!rootChildren0Children0Children0.isEmpty()) {
        rootChildren0Children0Children.add(rootChildren0Children0Children0);
    }
    if (!rootChildren0Children0Children.isEmpty()) {
        rootChildren0Children0.append("children", rootChildren0Children0Children);
    }
    if (!rootChildren0Children0.isEmpty()) {
        rootChildren0Children.add(rootChildren0Children0);
    }
    if (!rootChildren0Children.isEmpty()) {
        rootChildren0.append("children", rootChildren0Children);
    }
    if (!rootChildren0Children1.isEmpty()) {
        rootChildren0Children.add(rootChildren0Children1);
    }
    if (!rootChildren0Children.isEmpty()) {
        rootChildren0.append("children", rootChildren0Children);
    }
    if (!rootChildren0Children2.isEmpty()) {
        rootChildren0Children.add(rootChildren0Children2);
    }
    if (!rootChildren0Children.isEmpty()) {
        rootChildren0.append("children", rootChildren0Children);
    }
    if (!rootChildren0.isEmpty()) {
        rootChildren.add(rootChildren0);
    }
    if (!rootChildren.isEmpty()) {
        root.append("children", rootChildren);
    }
    if (!rootChildren1.isEmpty()) {
        rootChildren.add(rootChildren1);
    }
    if (!rootChildren.isEmpty()) {
        root.append("children", rootChildren);
    }

    System.out.println(root.toJson());
```